# React native app crashes on logout for first launch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I have been created a react native app,on first launch of the app it go to the route appjs->onboardingscreen->loginscreen->tabscreen and in tab screen there are 3 tabs on the last tab profile there is the function that clear context and storage to log out but on preforming that it crashes.that error shows that it previous stack context value is null but on second launch the app work perfect on the route loginscreen->tabscrenn afterwords its log out perfect

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import HeaderLayout from "../../Components/HeaderLayout";
import Statusbar from "../../Components/Statusbar";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import Profile_Detail_Tab from "../../Components/Profile_Detail_Tab";
import AuthContext from "../../auth/context";
import storage from "../../auth/storage";
import { useBottomTabBarHeight } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  const tabheight = useBottomTabBarHeight();
  const { userData, setUserData } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const key = "@storage_Key";
  console.log("profile");

  const handleLogOut = () => {
    setUserData(null);
    storage.removeData(key);
    console.log("logout");
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Statusbar />
      <HeaderLayout title={"Profile"} />
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffffff", paddingBottom: tabheight, marginBottom: 10 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 100,
              backgroundColor: "#04213c",
              borderBottomEndRadius: 50,
              borderBottomStartRadius: 50,
            }}
          />

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" size={140} color="white" />
          </View>
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 30, padding: 10, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            {userData.detail.first_name + " " + userData.detail.last_name}
          </Text>

          <View>
            <Profile_Detail_Tab text_color="#000000" color="#ffffff" Title="email" value={userData.detail.email} />
            <Profile_Detail_Tab text_color="#000000" color="#ffffff" Title="phone" value={userData.detail.mobile} />
            <Profile_Detail_Tab
              text_color="#000000"
              color="#ffffff"
              Title="map-marker-outline"
              value={userData.detail.work_station}
            />
            <Profile_Detail_Tab
              text_color="#000000"
              color="#ffffff"
              Title="account-hard-hat"
              value={userData.detail.role}
            />
            <Profile_Detail_Tab
              text_color="#000000"
              color="#ffffff"
              Title="message-reply-text"
              value={userData.detail.designation}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogOut}>
              <Profile_Detail_Tab text_color="#ffffff" color="#04213c" Title="logout" value="Logout" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#d1c9d3",
    borderRadius: 15,
    width: 140,
    height: 140,
    borderRadius: 70,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginTop: -80,
  },
});

export default Profile;
```

[

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Tabs from "./src/Navigation/Tabs";
import StackNavigation from "./src/Navigation/StackNavigation";
import AuthContext from "./src/auth/context";
import storage from "./src/auth/storage";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import AuthNavigation from "./src/Navigation/AuthNavigation";
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const key = "@storage_Key";
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkdata();
  }, []);
  console.log("App js");

  const checkdata = async () => {
    const appData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isAppFirstLaunched");

    if (appData == null) {
      setIsFirstLaunch(true);
      AsyncStorage.setItem("isAppFirstLaunched", "false");
    } else {
      setIsFirstLaunch(false);
    }
  };

  // console.log(isFirstLaunch);
  const getToken = async () => {
    const data = await storage.getData(key);

    if (data == null) return;
    setUserData(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

  console.log(userData);
  if (!isReady) return <AppLoading startAsync={getToken} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} onError={console.warn} />;

  if (isFirstLaunch == null) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  } else if (isFirstLaunch == true) {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StackNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <NavigationContainer>{userData ? <Tabs /> : <AuthNavigation />}</NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WUj6.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1s9N.jpg)

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Tabs from "./src/Navigation/Tabs";
import StackNavigation from "./src/Navigation/StackNavigation";
import AuthContext from "./src/auth/context";
import storage from "./src/auth/storage";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import AuthNavigation from "./src/Navigation/AuthNavigation";
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const key = "@storage_Key";
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkdata();
  }, []);
  console.log("App js");

  const checkdata = async () => {
    const appData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isAppFirstLaunched");

    if (appData == null) {
      setIsFirstLaunch(true);
      AsyncStorage.setItem("isAppFirstLaunched", "false");
    } else {
      setIsFirstLaunch(false);
    }
  };

  // console.log(isFirstLaunch);
  const getToken = async () => {
    const data = await storage.getData(key);

    if (data == null) return;
    setUserData(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

  console.log(userData);
  if (!isReady) return <AppLoading startAsync={getToken} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} onError={console.warn} />;

  if (isFirstLaunch == null) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  } else if (isFirstLaunch == true) {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StackNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <NavigationContainer>{userData ? <Tabs /> : <AuthNavigation />}</NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `userData?.detail`  instead of  `userData.detail` coz its getting undefined  where you shown error in image

Comment: on log out i'm setting it to null ,The problem is the error is occurring only in the first launch of the application after pressing the logout .once it installed( on restarting )it working perfect.

Comment: the state is updated to undefined but on first launch its not loging out (on log out function it should go to login screen) and going login screen.on log which i get is route is appjs->loginscreen->tabscreen->profile so still the profile screen shown with no data.but after restarting the app it work perfect